# How to print this pattern using C++?

Tags: c++

How to print

```
*000
**00
***0
****
```

Here we have to take the no. of lines as input from the user and then print the pattern.I am able to print the *'s but unable to print the 0's along with them

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I can print the stars using 2 loops but dont know how to print these 0's

Comment: Do you want us to make your homework ? Post your code please.

Comment: k i will post the code

Comment: this is not my homework this question was asked in a technical interview.

Comment: Hint: you know how to use a loop to count *up*. Do you know how to use a loop to count *down?*

Comment: actually here we are required to take the no. of lines as input from the user and then print the lines

Comment: Please put all the requirements in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of questions are usually intended to test the skill of using loops efficiently.

Use this:

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int length; //no of lines
        cout<<"Enter the number of lines"<<endl;
        cin>>length;
        cout<<endl;
        for( int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
             for( int j=0;j<=i;j++ )
             {
                  cout<<"*";
             }
             for( int k=length-1; k>i;k-- )
             {
                  cout<<"0";
             }
             cout<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Change the value of length to change the number of lines

Comment: yea i will take the input from the user using cout

Comment: btw thax a lot it really helped

Comment: Updated to take user input, guess you got what you wanted

Answer (score 2):

```
cout << "*000" << endl << "**00" << endl << "***0" << endl << "****" << endl;
```

because few beers in I'll start to answer silly questions with equally silly answers. :D good luck for the tech interview.

Comment: I was tempted to post exactly the same answer. OP must have some requirements they haven't mentioned :-) But I would replace most `endl` by `'\n'` where applicable.

Comment: :D aye, I thought about being serious for a second too... but this unrolled loop fits their requirements.. and if I DID give her a serious answer then she might pass the tech interview for a job she's not qualified for. Time for bed I think, before the internet takes control...

Comment: i am sorry actually i forgot to mention the requirements earlier

Comment: i got rejected thatsy i asked this question so that i dont repeat my mistake again

Comment: Well okay, I'll actually try to help :D to be honest, this isn't a C++ question but a general problem-solving question.  I would suggest a simpler language to start learning with; I would recommend Python for four reasons: 1) it manages your memory, 2) no pointers, 3) no templates, 4) it has a much more broader base library.  C++ is my preferred language, but Python is a close second - and if you're struggling with this level of question then you should be learning & practicing problem solving first, NOT trying to learn a language as complex as C++.  Good luck on the next interview ;)

Comment: thx a lot nevelis its just coz of ppl like u newbie's hesitate to ask questions on stack overflow

Comment: I still think my advice is fair; you're biting off far more than you can chew.  By all means, learn C++, but learn how to solve simple problems like these first. As I said, a simpler language will be much easier to learn problem solving; because you will spend less time learning the language, and more time learning problem solving skills.  I guarantee you'll be writing more than two nested for-loops in the real world :) If I offended you then I'm sorry you feel that way, but that's the best advice I can offer at this stage in your journey.

Comment: @user3324960 Being a newbie is not an excuse for posting poor questions. There's an [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) about this. Have a look at it, and hopefully next time it will result in you getting better answers.

Comment: One last reiteration before I hit the hay; you said: "thatsy i asked this question so that i dont repeat my mistake again" - you will probably never get asked this exact question again. This is why problem solving is a much more important skill than C++. One question I ask in my interviews is "Print every Friday 13 for a given year", and then "Extend it to print every Friday 13 for a given century".  You need to be able to solve these problems yourself, rather than memorize the answers.  This site has some good C/C++ challenges for beginners: http://www.cprogramming.com/challenge.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for something like:

```
int lines = 4;   // lines you want to print
for (int i=1; i<=lines; i++)
{
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        cout << "*";
    for (int j=0; j<lines-i; j++)
        cout << "0";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do with printf than with cout. Use this:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
    printf("%.*s%.*s\n", i, "****", 4 - i, "0000");
}
```

printf allows the width and precision fields to be specified as part of the parameter list, unlike cout where it is hardcoded inline. With that hint, I will leave it to you to figure out the rest. Please comment below in case of any questions. :)

Comment: i havent used printf to print anything lemme check

Comment: i thought its c coz in c we use printf and scanf

Comment: Uhm, I am afraid you need to work on your basics even before you start worrying about interview questions like these.

Answer (score 0):

What about sticking with 0-indexes and clearly defined invariants?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

  int lines = 5;

  // we have written i rows thus far
  // write [i, lines) rows
  for (int i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
  {

    // we have written j stars thus far
    // write [j, i + 1) stars
    for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j)
    {
      cout << "*";
    }

    // we have written k zeros thus far
    // write [k, lines - 1 - i) zeros
    for (int k = 0; k < lines - 1 - i; ++k)
    {
      cout << "0";
    }

    cout << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```